# handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:withResponseInfo: launches App when reply iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using

> (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
>   handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier
>   forRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
>   withResponseInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary *)responseInfo
>   completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)())completionHandler

to reply Push Notifications. Under iOS 9, I could reply without opening my App but under iOS 10 it launches the App automatically.

```
UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData
completionHandler(fetchResult);
```

And in watchOS 3 I can not reply to Push on Apple Watch
Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: the `reply ` means handle the push notification?

Comment: Handle push notification with UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput